# Can i block appearing control center in ios7 on some views?

Tags: controls, center, ios7

I need to disable control center on one key view in case i use "swipe up" gesture for navigation on that view controller

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

When you "swipe up" it avoid to reveal the control centre. The gestures work normally for your application and it shows only a grabber

Comment: This is very much the best answer! Thank you!
When you do this, it now required *two* swipes to get the Control Center (up-swipe) or Notification Center (down-swipe). I notice that some games have this behavior, and now mine does too. Thank you!
(Can also advise users to disable Control Center in Settings.)

Answer (score 2):

Best workaround I've found for this is to present the view controller in full screen. (I'm not talking about the deprecated Full Screen property)

By doing so you force the notification \ control center to be triggered with two swipes instead of one. If the user swipes up or down he'll see a small arrow instead of the all notification\control center. Another swipe on that arrow will open the center view. There's no public way to disable it completely so this is your best bet.

Comment: View Controller in Full Screen is deprecated :-( I wish they had NSNotifications for when control center or notification center is presented just like the UIKeyBoard so that we can appropriately implement changes in our app.

Comment: If you'll present the view controller in full screen (a simple present with no status bar) will force the above to apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Control Center is a apple implemented feature. This is the same thing as notification center, which you also cannot disable.

Comment: see Marco Cattai's answer above, <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/> helps reduce accidental swipe-displays...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. But you can warn users that they can disable it from the "Settings" (not that I would suggest you do this, unless you want to make your users mad)